# Reorder multi select in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) with the `isMulti` prop to allow users to select from a list of months (January-December).  If the user selects the months out of order, I want the selected items to be reordered.

How can I reorder the selected items?

Here's a screenshot of what I want recorded:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
handleChange = (selectedOptions, action) => {
    selectedOptions.sort((a, b) => { // <=== THIS DOESN'T WORK
        return a.value - b.value;    // <=== THIS DOESN'T WORK
    });                              // <=== THIS DOESN'T WORK
    this.setState({selectedOptions});
    const {onSelectedOption} = this.props;
    onSelectedOption(selectedOptions);
};


render() {
    const {selectedOptions, options, error} = this.state;
    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                isMulti
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                value={selectedOptions}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                options={options}
                isClearable={false}
                isSearchable={false}
                placeholder="Months..."
                classNamePrefix="react-select"
            />
            {error && <div className="alert alert-danger">{error}</div>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The selected months are stored in the state?

Comment: Please provide some code of your implementation to help solving your question.

Comment: Do selectedItemsArray.sort() after pushing the newly selected Item, after this set the state.

Comment: @ShivamGupta Yes, it's stored in the state but reordering them after the user has selected the items doesn't work.

Comment: @mthrsj yes but reordering those values doesn't work

Comment: @Rallen I updated the question with my code.

Comment: Would you mind also providing the structure of one of your month options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really close from the solution except the way you compare the values is wrong:

```
selectedOptions.sort((a, b) => { 
  return a.value - b.value; --> this returns NaN
});
```

a and b values are both `Strings` so you should do:

```
selectedOptions.sort((a, b) =>
  a.value.localeCompare(b.value)
);
```

if you want to order them in alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks for this, I can't believe I missed that!